# Issues regarding dynamically loading master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to get a master page to load dynamically when it is detected that the device accessing the site is a mobile device.
However I can't seem to get it to load the correct master page as it always loads the default primary.master regardless of whether the device is detected as a mobile or desktop system.

Can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page


{
protected void Page_PreInt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true)
        {
           MasterPageFile = "~/Mater Pages / Mobile Primary.master";
        }
        else
        {
           MasterPageFile = "~/Mater Pages /Primary.master";
            base.OnPreInit(e);
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //   If for any reason this page needs to be made inaccessible then    remove the tags on either side of the text//

        //Response.Redirect("~/Error Page.aspx");//
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that files exist at those locations?  You've misspelled the word master in both cases.  Also, you have have spaces in your file names, but maybe that's a problem from pasting the code here?

Comment: The files are definitely in the root ~/Mater Pages (not got around to re-naming in) and the Mobile primary.master file has a space between the words mobile and primary. Could that be what is causing the error?

Comment: @WillR For dynamic master page binding, I think you need to focus little further [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-cs) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice** is not reliable. The following helper method could detect a little bit more.

If you want reliable device detection, you want to use commercial service such as [51Degrees](https://51degrees.com/device-detection).

*Event should be **Page_PreInit** (not **Page_PreInt**); you have a typo.*

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // *** For debugging, I inverted if statement. You should do the same. ****
    if (!IsMobileBrowser(HttpContext.Current))
        MasterPageFile = "~/MaterPages/Primary.master";
    else
        MasterPageFile = "~/MaterPages/MobilePrimary.master";

    // *** You do not need to call base.OnPreInit(e); ***
}

public static bool IsMobileBrowser(HttpContext context)
{
    // first try built in asp.net check
    if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // then try checking for the http_x_wap_profile header
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"] != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // then try checking that http_accept exists and contains wap
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"] != null &&
        context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToLower().Contains("wap"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Finally check the http_user_agent header variable for any one of the following
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
    {
        // List of all mobile types
        string[] mobiles =
            new[]
            {
                "android", "opera mini", "midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource",
                "240×320", "opwv", "chtml",
                "pda", "windows ce", "mmp/", "blackberry", "mib/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi",
                "phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio", "sie-", "sec-", "samsung", "htc", "mot-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony",
                "alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx", "nec", "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch",
                "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda",
                "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "dddi", "moto", "iphone"
            };

        // Check if the header contains that text
        var userAgent = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToLower();

        return mobiles.Any(userAgent.Contains);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that in the application and same problem. The site keeps using the default master page regardless

Comment: Did you invert the If statement? Also make sure you did not explicitly assign ***MasterPageFile*** at `<%@ page %>` direct inside ASPX.

Comment: Just checked the ASPX document and it specifically states a master page.

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Mater Pages/Primary.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

Comment: Well, you need to remove `MasterPageFile="~/Mater Pages/Primary.master"` from ***@ Page*** directive.

Comment: Removed the code from the .aspx file and get the following error 'System.Web.HttpException: Content controls are allowed only in content page that references a master page.'

Comment: I updated my answer. You have a typo in ***Page_PreInit***, and remove ***base.OnPreInit(e);***.